# Count column where value is equal row id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this.

```
id | name | desc | parent
-------------------------
1  | abc  | def  | 0
2  | abc  | def  | 1
3  | abc  | def  | 1
4  | abc  | def  | 1
5  | abc  | def  | 2
6  | abc  | def  | 3
```

And what I need to get is this, get all rows and count how many rows have `parent` same as id of actual row. And all must be order by this count.

```
id | name | desc | parent | count
-------------------------
1  | abc  | def  | 0      | 3
2  | abc  | def  | 1      | 1
3  | abc  | def  | 1      | 1
4  | abc  | def  | 1      | 0
5  | abc  | def  | 2      | 0
6  | abc  | def  | 3      | 0
```

I ended with this but actually it not works :/

```
select c.pocet, a.* from posts a, (select count(*) as pocet from posts b where b.parent=a.id ) c
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you add what would be the result for the given sample of data?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the number of children each parent has?

Comment: @lliev you have result what I need in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example. Add more columns as needed.

```
select 
t.id,t.parent,coalesce(x.cnt,0) as cnt
from t left join
(select parent,count(*) as cnt
 from t
 group by parent) x
on x.parent = t.id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cfef2/8)

Comment: This is the answer!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You were actually close, you just need switch to a Scalar Subquery:

```
select a.*,
  (select count(*) from posts b where b.parent=a.id) as pocet
from posts a
```